# Can't access object made by ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: dataString,
           url: "app/changeQuantity",
           success: function(data) {
$('#table').append('<tr><td><a id="uid">click</a></td></tr>');

});
```

as you can see it makes new row in #table. But this new objects made by ajax are not accessible from next functions. Result from ajax is not a regullar part of DOM, or what is the reason for this strange behavior?

```
$('#uid').on('click', function () {
alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: And where are you accessing it????

Comment: where the code for click on uid is positioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ajax` calls are asynchronous. So whatever you do with the `data` you need to do it in a callback within the `success` function (that is the callback which is called when the ajax call returns successfully).

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click','#uid', function () {
alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: Not bad, but it works only in case, if you do not have more than one result from ajax call. If you have more result with different id's and  need work with $(this) selector, it's unfortunatelly not applicable.

Comment: @JiříValoušek, you cannot have more than one result. How can you have more results? Also, inside the function you can use $(this), also, dumping all the code inside success handler isn't too good

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) doesn't work like that. Use have to give a parent which not loaded by ajax, and the specify ajax load element like this

```
$('#table').on('click','#uid' ,function () {
// what ever code you like 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is simple and complex at the same time. Simple to solve but complex if you are getting started with javascript...

Your event handler - onclick is being fired and bound to an object that doesnt yet exist.

So when you append the object to the #table, you need to set up your click handler as the object now exists.

So in your success part of the ajax return add the click handler event there.

```
success: function(data) {
           $('#table').append('<tr><td><a id="uid">click</a></td></tr>');
           $('#uid').on('click', function () {
              alert('ok');
           });
       });
```

Or how about you make it dynamic and create a function to do it for you.

```
function bindClick(id) {
  $('#' + id).click(function() {
     //Do stuff here
     console.log('I made it here' + id);
    });
}
```

Then:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#table').append('<tr><td><a id="uid">click</a></td></tr>');
     bindClick(uid);
  });
}
```

This is a super contrived example but you get the idea you just need to make the rest of it dynamic as well. for example some name and counter generated id number: id1, id2, id3...

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this, add this `$('#uid').on('click', function () {` into the success

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: dataString,
       url: "app/changeQuantity",
       success: function(data) {
           $('#table').append('<tr><td><a id="uid">click</a></td></tr>');
           $('#uid').on('click', function () {
              alert('ok');
           });
       });
});
```